# Problems with JdbcCurserdReader it seams to read ok but writer gets chunck containing a list of the same item

Tags: spring-batch

## Problem:

**When processing the step the after read listeners gives a correct reading, but the before write listener shows the chunk contains multiple copies of the same item. instead of the 20 items read.**

### Output of after read listener

```
2020-06-05 16:22:57,360 | INFO | 22636 | o.s.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler | TaskExecutor-11 | Executing step: [migrate.document]

***AFTER READ : DataPumpObj [properties=DACTIONDATE: 2020-06-05 08:50:00.0, DACTIONMILLIS: 644738, ID: 10, column1: 10, user: sysadmin]

***AFTER READ : DataPumpObj [properties=DACTIONDATE: 2020-06-05 08:50:00.0, DACTIONMILLIS: 704774, ID: 11, column1: 11, user: sysadmin]

***AFTER READ : DataPumpObj [properties=DACTIONDATE: 2020-06-05 08:50:00.0, DACTIONMILLIS: 764811, ID: 12, column1: 12, user: sysadmin]

***AFTER READ : DataPumpObj [properties=DACTIONDATE: 2020-06-05 08:50:00.0, DACTIONMILLIS: 824837, ID: 13, column1: 13, user: sysadmin]

***AFTER READ : DataPumpObj [properties=DACTIONDATE: 2020-06-05 08:50:00.0, DACTIONMILLIS: 884877, ID: 14, column1: 14, user: sysadmin]

***AFTER READ : DataPumpObj [properties=DACTIONDATE: 2020-06-05 08:50:00.0, DACTIONMILLIS: 944905, ID: 15, column1: 15, user: sysadmin]

***AFTER READ : DataPumpObj [properties=DACTIONDATE: 2020-06-05 08:50:00.0, DACTIONMILLIS: 1004944, ID: 16, column1: 16, user: sysadmin]

***AFTER READ : DataPumpObj [properties=DACTIONDATE: 2020-06-05 08:50:00.0, DACTIONMILLIS: 1064979, ID: 17, column1: 17, user: sysadmin]

***AFTER READ : DataPumpObj [properties=DACTIONDATE: 2020-06-05 08:50:00.0, DACTIONMILLIS: 1125016, ID: 18, column1: 18, user: sysadmin]

***AFTER READ : DataPumpObj [properties=DACTIONDATE: 2020-06-05 08:52:00.0, DACTIONMILLIS: 1164389, ID: 19, column1: 37, user: weblogic]

***AFTER READ : DataPumpObj [properties=DACTIONDATE: 2020-06-05 08:52:00.0, DACTIONMILLIS: 1233974, ID: 20, column1: 38, user: weblogic]
```

### Output of before write listener

```
DataPumpObj [properties=DACTIONDATE: 2020-06-05 08:52:00.0, DACTIONMILLIS: 1233974, ID: 20, column1: 38, user: weblogic]

DataPumpObj [properties=DACTIONDATE: 2020-06-05 08:52:00.0, DACTIONMILLIS: 1233974, ID: 20, column1: 38, user: weblogic]

DataPumpObj [properties=DACTIONDATE: 2020-06-05 08:52:00.0, DACTIONMILLIS: 1233974, ID: 20, column1: 38, user: weblogic]

DataPumpObj [properties=DACTIONDATE: 2020-06-05 08:52:00.0, DACTIONMILLIS: 1233974, ID: 20, column1: 38, user: weblogic]

DataPumpObj [properties=DACTIONDATE: 2020-06-05 08:52:00.0, DACTIONMILLIS: 1233974, ID: 20, column1: 38, user: weblogic]

DataPumpObj [properties=DACTIONDATE: 2020-06-05 08:52:00.0, DACTIONMILLIS: 1233974, ID: 20, column1: 38, user: weblogic]

DataPumpObj [properties=DACTIONDATE: 2020-06-05 08:52:00.0, DACTIONMILLIS: 1233974, ID: 20, column1: 38, user: weblogic]
```

### Code snippets

```
@Override
    @Bean(name = "ItemReader")
    public ItemReader<DataPumpObj> databaseItemReader() {
        propertieSetter();

        SynchronizedItemStreamReader<DataPumpObj> synchronizedItemStreamReader = new SynchronizedItemStreamReader<DataPumpObj>();

        JdbcCursorItemReader<DataPumpObj> reader = new JdbcCursorItemReader<>();
          reader.setDataSource(dataSource);
          reader.setSql(SQL_GET);
          reader.setFetchSize(FETCH_SIZE);
          reader.setVerifyCursorPosition(true);
          reader.setRowMapper(new DataPumpObjMapper(this.migratedfields));
          synchronizedItemStreamReader.setDelegate(reader);
          return synchronizedItemStreamReader;
    }

    private void propertieSetter() {
        if (this.migratedfields == null) {

            this.migratedfields = getjdbctemplate().query(GET_MIGRATIONFIELDS_WHERE, new FieldMapper());
            this.SQL_GET = setGetSql(migratedfields, "MIGRATIONDOCUMENTHISTORY");
        }
    }
```

The rowmapper that i use looks as followed:

```
package com.oracle.mt.rowmapper;

import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Timestamp;
import java.util.List;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapper;

import com.oracle.mt.dbo.DataPumpObj;
import com.oracle.mt.dbo.Field;

public class DataPumpObjMapper implements RowMapper<DataPumpObj>{
    final static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DataPumpObjMapper.class);

    private List<Field> migratedfields = null;

    public DataPumpObjMapper(List<Field> migratedfields) {
        super();
        this.migratedfields = migratedfields;
    }

    @Override
    public DataPumpObj mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
        DataPumpObj base = new DataPumpObj();

        base.setProperties(migratedfields);
        base.getProperties().forEach(field ->{

                    String column= field.getSourceFieldName().toLowerCase();
                    if(field.getType().equalsIgnoreCase("Date")) {                          
                        try {
                            Timestamp temp = rs.getTimestamp(column);
                            if (temp == null) {
                                field.setValue(null);
                            }else {
                                field.setValue(temp.toString());
                            }
                        } catch (SQLException e) {
                            logger.error("DEBUG MAPPER: SQLException has been thrown: " + e);

                        }   
                    }
                    else if (field.getType().equalsIgnoreCase("String")) {
                        try {
                            field.setValue(rs.getString(column));
                        } catch (SQLException e) {
                            logger.error("DEBUG MAPPER: SQLException has been thrown : " + e);
                        }
                    }else if(field.getType().equalsIgnoreCase("Int")) {
                        try {
                            int temp =  ((Number) rs.getObject(column)).intValue();
                            field.setValue(""+temp);
                        } catch (SQLException e) {
                            logger.error("DEBUG MAPPER: SQLException has been thrown : " + e);
                        }
                    }
                });
        return base;
    };

}
```

Datapump object:

```
public class DataPumpObj {

    private List<Field> properties;

    public List<Field> getProperties() {
        return properties;
    }

    public void setProperties(List<Field> properties) {
        this.properties = properties;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder temp = new StringBuilder("DataPumpObj [properties=" );
        temp.append(properties.stream()
                .map(field -> {return field.getSourceFieldName() + ": " + field.getValue();})
                .collect(Collectors.joining(", ")));
        temp.append("]");
        return temp.toString();
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((properties == null) ? 0 : properties.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        DataPumpObj other = (DataPumpObj) obj;
        if (properties == null) {
            if (other.properties != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!properties.equals(other.properties))
            return false;
        return true;
    }
```

Job Definition:
There is a task-executor defined but maxpoolsize is set to 1, for testing purposes.

```
<batch:job id="migrate" restartable="false">
<batch:step id="migrate.documentHistory">
            <batch:tasklet task-executor="taskExecutor" throttle-limit="${thread.maxpoolsize}">
                <batch:chunk reader="ItemReader" writer="datapumpWriter" commit-interval="${batch.commitinterval}">
                </batch:chunk>
                <batch:listeners>
                    <batch:listener ref="datapumpWriteListener"></batch:listener>
                    <batch:listener ref="datapumpReaderListener"></batch:listener>
                </batch:listeners>
            </batch:tasklet>
        </batch:step>
</batch:job>
```

Comment: Can you post your job definition?

Comment: Does `DataPumpObj` class implements `equals`/`hashcode` methods correctly? Do you have an item processor that transforms items?

Comment: Yes, I have implemented the equals and hashcode methods I have added the class to the description.

Comment: added job description

Comment: I do not have an item processor, i want to add it once this is working.